# Excel VBA to update powerpoint text box

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

With the help of below coding, I am able to open the powerpoint file but it is not updating the textbox.

I am getting an error as "Object variable or with block variable not set".

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim newslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim slideCtr As Integer
Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
Set pres = PPT.Presentations.Open( _
    "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Process Coach certificate template.pptx")
slideCtr = 1
Set tb = newslide.Shapes("TextBox1")
tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "OK"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("TextBox1").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "qwerty"
```

To get the name of the shape just right (in an input box so that you can copy it), select it and run:

```
a = InputBox("The name of the selected shape is:", "Name of the Shape", PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name)
```

to change it, while you have it selected, try:

```
PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "TextBox2"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Its really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Error is taking place on the `Set tb` line because you never initialize `newslide`, or at least you don't show it here.

Assuming your text box is on slide one you can do something like the following (add before `Set tb`):

```
Set newslide = pres.Slides(1)
```

---

Also make sure the text box you want is actually "TextBox1".  By default the names usually have a space before the number like "TextBox 1".

I tested your code with this change to verify it works.  Full code here:

```
Sub test()
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim newslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim slideCtr As Integer
    Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape

    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    Set pres = PPT.Presentations.Open( _
        "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Process Coach certificate template.pptx")
    slideCtr = 1

    Set newslide = pres.Slides(1)

    Set tb = newslide.Shapes("TextBox1")
    tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: @A.S.H - I just realized your deleted answer is essentially the same.  Un-delete yours and I'll remove mine & plus 1

Comment: Hi, never mind. I deleted my answer because I smelled some "XY pattern" in the question (see comments below my deleted answer). However I'm glad to know that the OP found it helpful, for the least it takes them one step ahead. :)